# HippoMock : mocking just a part of class

Tags: c++, unit-testing, mocking, hippomocks

I would like to know if with HippoMock it is possible to mock just a parts of a class.

Example

```
class aClass
{
public:
    virtual void method1() = 0;

    void method2(){ 
        do
            doSomething;      // not a functon 
            method1();
        while(condition);
    };
};
```

I would like to mock just method1 in order to test the method 2

Clearly I use HippoMock and I have a bug in method2 so I made a unit test in order to correct it and be sure it will not come back. But i don't find the way to do it.

I try this

```
TEST(testMethod2)
{
    MockRepository mock;
    aClass *obj = mock.Mock<aClass>();
    mock.ExpectCall(obj , CPXDetector::method1);
    obj->method2();
}
```

Is there some solution in native cpp ? With an other mock framework ?

Thanks a lot

Ambroise Petitgenêt

Comment: I don't understand your question (If I do understand it, the answer is "yes"). Possibly you are using the term "Mock" wrong. Can write an example of the unit test you want to write with the mock?

Comment: The unit test i want to write looks like
<pre> 
TEST(testMethod2)
{
    MockRepository mocks;
    A *a = mocks.Mock<A>();
    mocks.ExpectCall(a, A::method1);
    a->method2();
}<code>

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 parts to this answer. First is, yes it's easy to do this. Second is, if you need to structure a test this way you often have an unfortunate class design - this commonly happens when you need to put legacy software under test, where the class design can't reasonably be fixed.

How to test this? As far as I remember you can use Hippomocks for this, but because I haven't used it in a while, I don't remember off the top of my head how to do it. Because you asked for any solution, even those using a different framework, I suggest using the direct approach instead of using hippomocks:

```
class bClass : public aClass
{
    int _counter;
public:
    bClass() : aClass(), _counter(0){}
    void method1() { _counter++; }
    int NumCallsToMethod1() const { return _counter; }
};

TEST(testMethod2)
{
    bClass testThis;
    testThis.method2();
    TEST_EQUALS(1,testThis.NumCallsToMethod1());
}
```

or, if `method1` is `const`:

```
class bClass : public aClass
{
    mutable int _counter;
public:
    bClass() : aClass(), _counter(0){}
    void method1() const { _counter++; }
    int NumCallsToMethod1() const { return _counter; }
};
```

Comment: First yes I'm working with legacy code and I can't refactor all.
And second your solution is nice, I like it

Comment: I think the above pattern, and a couple of others are described in this book: http://www.amazon.com/Working-Effectively-Legacy-Michael-Feathers/dp/0131177052

Comment: I'm reading the books you send to me. It is very interesting. Thanks a lot

Comment: HippoMocks can do this in case of a non-virtual member function calling a virtual one - you can only mock virtual ones. In this case though, as you're relying on implementation details of your mock I'd use @Peter's solution still, if only to make it explicit.